# Why is this compute shader so much slower than vertex shader?

Tags: vertex-shader, direct3d11, compute-shader

I'm exploring using a compute shader to apply bone deformation to mesh vertices rather than a vertex shader with stream output. I've found the compute shader executes far slower than the vertex shader but before I write it off, I want to be sure I'm not doing something wrong.

With my test data of 100,000 vertices and 1,000 frames of animation data for 300 bones, the vertex shader runs in around 0.22ms while the compute shader takes 4x as long at 0.85ms. The timing is done via D3D API timer queries (rather than a cpu timer).

deform_structs.hlsl

```
struct Vertex {
  float3 position : POSITION;
  float3 normal : NORMAL;
  float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
  float3 tangent : TANGENT;
  float4 color : COLOR;
};

struct BoneWeights {
  uint index;
  float weight;
};

StructuredBuffer<matrix> g_bone_array : register(t0);
Buffer<uint> g_bone_offsets : register(t1);
Buffer<uint> g_bone_counts : register(t2);
StructuredBuffer<BoneWeights> g_bone_weights : register(t3);
```

bone_deform_cs.hlsl

```
#include "deform_structs.hlsl"

StructuredBuffer<Vertex> g_input_vertex : register(t4);
RWStructuredBuffer<Vertex> g_output_vertex : register(u0);

[numthreads(64,1,1)]
void BoneDeformCS(uint id : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
  Vertex vert = g_input_vertex[id.x];
  uint offset = g_bone_offsets[id.x];
  uint count = g_bone_counts[id.x];

  matrix bone_matrix = 0;
  for (uint i = offset; i < (offset + count); ++i) {
    BoneWeights weight_info = g_bone_weights[i];
    bone_matrix += weight_info.weight * g_bone_array[weight_info.index];
  }

  vert.position = mul(float4(vert.position,1), bone_matrix).xyz;
  vert.normal = normalize(mul(vert.normal, (float3x3)bone_matrix));
  vert.tangent = normalize(mul(vert.tangent, (float3x3)bone_matrix));
  g_output_vertex[id.x] = vert;
}
```

bone_deform_vs.hlsl

```
#include "deform_structs.hlsl"

void BoneDeformVS(uint id : SV_VertexID, Vertex vsin, out Vertex vsout) {
  uint offset = g_bone_offsets[id];
  uint count = g_bone_counts[id];

  matrix bone_matrix = 0;
  for (uint i = offset; i < (offset + count); ++i) {
    BoneWeights bone_info = g_bone_weights[i];
    bone_matrix += bone_info.weight * g_bone_array[bone_info.index];
  }

  vsout.position = mul(float4(vsin.position,1), bone_matrix).xyz;
  vsout.normal = normalize(mul(vsin.normal, (float3x3)bone_matrix));
  vsout.tangent = normalize(mul(vsin.tangent, (float3x3)bone_matrix));
  vsout.texcoord = vsin.texcoord;
  vsout.color = vsin.color;
}
```

Comparing the contents of the buffers once they've run, they are identical and contain the expected values.

I suspect that maybe I'm executing the compute shader incorrectly, spawning too many threads? Do I have the number I pass to `Dispatch` wrong? Since it is a 1 dimensional row of data, it made sense to me to use `[numthreads(64,1,1)]`. I've tried various values from 32-1024. 64 seems to be the sweet spot as it's the minimum needed for efficient use of AMD GPUs. Anyway. When I call `Dispatch`, I ask it to execute `(vertex_count / 64) + (vertex_count % 64 != 0) ? 1 : 0`. For 100,000 vertices, the call ends up being `Dispatch(1563,1,1)`.

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView * srvs[] = {bone_array_srv, bone_offset_srv,
                                     bone_count_srv, bone_weights_srv,
                                     cs_vertices_srv};
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView * uavs[] = {cs_output_uav};
UINT srv_count = sizeof(srvs) / sizeof(srvs[0]);
UINT uav_count = sizeof(uavs) / sizeof(uavs[0]);
UINT thread_group_count = vertex_count / 64 + (vertex_count % 64 != 0) ? 1 : 0;

context->CSSetShader(cs, nullptr, 0);
context->CSSetShaderResources(0, srv_count, srvs);
context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, uav_count, uavs);
context->Dispatch(thread_group_count, 1, 1);
```

And this is how the vertex shader is executed:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView * srvs[] = {bone_array_srv, bone_offset_srv,
                                     bone_count_srv, bone_weights_srv};
UINT srv_count = sizeof(srvs) / sizeof(srvs[0]);
UINT stride = 0;
UINT offset = 0;

context->GSSetShader(streamout_gs, nullptr, 0);
context->VSSetShader(vs, nullptr, 0);
context->VSSetShaderResources(0, srv_count, srvs);
context->SOSetTargets(1, &vs_output_buf, &offset);
context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST);
context->IASetInputLayout(vs_input_layout);
context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vs_vertices, &stride, &offset);
context->Draw(vertex_count, 0);
```

Or is the answer just that reading from a shader resource view and writing to an unordered access view is just far slower than reading from a vertex buffer and writing to a stream output buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’m just learning how to work with compute shaders, so I’m not an expert. Regarding your bone calculation I’m sure that the CS should work at least as fast as the VS. Intuition tells me that `numthreads (64,1,1)`  is less efficient than something like `numthreads (16,16,1)`. 
So you could give this approach a try:

1. Treat your linear buffer as if it had a  quadratic layout, with x and y size being the same
2. Compute x/y-size as `size = ceil (sqrt (numvertices))`
3. Use dispat`ch(size / 16, size / 16)` in your program and `numthreads (16,16,1)` in your hlsl file
4. Allocate a constant buffer where you copy your `size` and `numvertices` values
5. Instead of using `id.x` as index, you calculate your own (linear) index as `int index = id.y * size +id.x)`, (maybe id.xy is also possible as index)
6. In most cases `size * size` will be greater than `numvertices`, so you’ll end up with more threads than vertices. You can block these extra threads by adding a condition in your hlsl function:

   ```
   int index = id.y * size +id.x;
   if (index < numvertices) { .. // your code follows
   ```

I hope that this approach speeds up your CS calculations.

================ EDIT ==================

My suggestion was based on my own timing tests. In order to verify my case I repeated these tests with more variances of the numthreads parameters.
I calculate the mandelbrot set over 1034 x 827 = 855,118 pixels. Here the results:

```
numthreads       Dispatch      groups  threads/  total
  x   y    fps     x     y             group     threads

  4   4    240    259   207    53445     16     855118
  8   8    550    129   103    13361     64     855118
 16  16    600     65    52     3340    256     855118
 32  32    580     32    26      835   1024     855118
 64   1    550     16   827    13361     64     855118
256   1    460      4   827     3340    256     855118
512   1    370      2   827     1670    512     855118
```

As you can see, the sweet spot -  numthreads(16,16,1) - creates the same #of thread groups (3340) as numthreads(256,1,1), but the performance is 30% better. 
Please note that the total thread count is (and must be) always the **same**! 
My GPU is a ATI 7790.

================ EDIT 2 ==================

In order to investigate deeper into your question about CS vs. VS speed I have re-viewed a very interesting channel 9 video (PDC09 presentation, held by Microsoft chief architect Chas Boyd about direct compute, see link below). In this presentation Boyd states that optimizing the thread layout (numthreads) can lead to twofold increase of throughput.

More interesting however is the part of his presentation (starting at minute 40) where he explains the correlation between UAVs and GPU memory layout (“Graphics vs. Compute I/O”). I don’t want to draw wrong conclusions from Boyds statements, but it seems at least possible, that Compute shaders bound via UAVs **do** have a **lower memory bandwidth** than other GPU shaders. If this were true we might have an explanation for the fact that UAVs can’t be bound to VS, for example (at least in version 11.0).

Since these memory access patterns also depend on hardware design, you should escalate your question directly to ATI / NVIDIA engineers.

CONCLUSION

I have absorbed tons of information about CS usage, but there was not the slightest indication that CS could run the same algorithm slower than VS. If that is really the case you have detected something that matters for all folks who use direct compute.

link: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/PDC/PDC09/P09-16

Comment: This is not correct. Hardware allocates compute threads linearly anyway, so NxMx1 is no more efficient than (NxM)x1x1.  Though the total number of threads could be increased.

Comment: Mike E wrote, that he tried numthreads (x,1,1) with x ranging from 32-1024. If you're right, can you think of any other reason why CS runs 4x slower than VS? Since the algorithms are the same in both cases and appear to be correct, the only difference is to optimize thread deployment, in one way or the other. At least I guess so.

Comment: Even if numthreads is a minor factor in your scenario, it can’t explain the fourfold difference between CS and VS computing. Because I’m still convinced that CS speed is not the problem, there remains one potential reason: How do you bind the CS output to the graphics pipeline? If there is a lot of binding / unbinding of resources involved, including copying of buffer(s), you can bet to have found the bottleneck.

Comment: Siegfried, for this test I'm actually not binding the output at all. I unbind the UAVs and SRVs at the end of executing the CS and that's when the timing ends. After the Dispatch, it just cleans up the state by setting the UAV/SRV slots to null and unbinding the CS. Same thing with the VS. Could it be that which is causing some overhead? Is something happening with the UAV buffer when it is unbound?

Comment: @Mike, I have extended my answer, see EDIT 2.  And please let us know if you get an answer from ATI / NVIDIA or other resources.

Comment: @SiegfriedStephan Thanks for the video link, it was enlightening. I suspect now that the issue is writing to that giant array from all groups and probably a better implementation would write to group shared memory then combine the results in post. I'll also look at finding an optimal group size for the number of temporary registers my code is using. Cheers.

Comment: @Mike E: Please give feedback if you succeed! I still wonder what's exactly the issue...

Comment: What kind of math is the table above? For instance, if you have Dispatch.x  = 65 and Dispatch.y = 52, how can you get 3340 groups? 65x52=3380!

Comment: Is it because of rounding?